# This page calls for XML namespace declared with prefix br but no taglibrary exists

Tags: jsf, netbeans, facelets

I just finished the Netbeans introduction to Hibernate tutorial ( http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/web/hibernate-webapp.html#01 ) and I am getting the following error:
"This page calls for XML namespace declared with prefix br but no taglibrary exists"

Now, I have seen a similar question somewhere else:
http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=5430327
but the answer is not listed there.  Or, if it is, then I am clearly missing it -- line one of my index.xhtml file reads "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml".  It also does not explain why, when I reload localhost:8080, the message disappears.

Here is my index.xhtml file:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
    <ui:composition template="./template.xhtml">
        <ui:define name="body">
            <h:form>
                <h:commandLink action="#{filmController.previous}" value="Previous #{filmController.pageSize}" rendered="#{filmController.hasPreviousPage}"/>
                <h:commandLink action="#{filmController.next}" value="Next #{filmController.pageSize}" rendered="#{filmController.hasNextPage}"/>
                <h:dataTable value="#{filmController.filmTitles}" var="item" border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" rowClasses="jsfcrud_odd_row,jsfcrud_even_row" rules="all" style="border:solid 1px">
                    <h:column>
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            <h:outputText value="Title"/>
                        </f:facet>
                        <h:outputText value="#{item.title}"/>
                    </h:column>
                    <h:column>
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            <h:outputText value="Description"/>
                        </f:facet>
                        <h:outputText value="#{item.description}"/>
                    </h:column>
                    <h:column>
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            <h:outputText value=" "/>
                        </f:facet>
                        <h:commandLink action="#{filmController.prepareView}" value="View"/>
                    </h:column>
                </h:dataTable>
                <br/>
                </h:form>
            </ui:define>
        </ui:composition>
    </html>
```

Comment: The question is about jsf and facelets, not hibernate.

Comment: Well, fair enough.  I was merely going through a tutorial and this was the problem.

Comment: See this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5177964/primefaces-warning-this-page-calls-for-xml-namespace)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem clearly comes from the `<br/>` tag, and facelets is trying to interpret it as a JSF/facelets tag with a prefix.

If we follow the standards, this tag should look like this `<br />` (with a space before the slash). Try it that way, and if it doesn't work, try removing it.

Answer (score 2):

I'm a few years late, but I have just done the same Hibernate tutorial, and faced exactly the same error. However, I do not think that the problem is related to the file index.xhtml. And while another poster is correct that the break tags should have a space, that change does not prevent the error "*This page calls for XML namespace declared with prefix br but no taglibrary exists*"

The problem lies in another xhtml file in the tutorial named **browse.xhtml**. You can see the content of that file using the tutorial link in the opening post. It contains an unmatched trailing </html> tag, and no reference to the http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml namespace.

Pasting the content of that file into a HTML validator (e.g. validator.w3.org ) highlights the problems.

The solution that worked for me was to add the missing opening <html> tag:

**<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">**

Alternatively, remove that unmatched trailing </html> tag, and add
**xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"** to the opening <ui:composition> tag.