# No TagLibrary associated to PrimeFaces's namespace

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, websphere, xml-namespaces

I found the similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5177964/warning-this-page-calls-for-xml-namespace-declared-with-prefix-tagname-but-no) but it doesn't helping me anymore. However i am facing the same problem. While running my application i get the followine error:

**Warning: The page /template/common.xhtml declares namespace http://primefaces.org/ui and uses the tag p:panel , but no TagLibrary associated to namespace.**

Below is a snippet of my index.xhtml :

```
<ui:composition template="/template/common.xhtml"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

    <ui:define name="profile">
```

And this is how my common.xhtml file looks (not putting the whole content, just namespaces and 1-2 lines) :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
          "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>Welcome to my website</title>
    <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="default.css" />
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <div id="header" style="margin: auto; width: 80%;">
        <p:panel>
```

As described by BalusC at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5180397/1175065), one must define xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml". I am doing the same. i.e. second line of index.xhtml file is doing the same. but still i am getting error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The PrimeFaces 3.x JAR file is missing in your webapp's `/WEB-INF/lib` folder. [Download](http://www.primefaces.org/downloads.html) and drop it in there. Or, if you're using PrimeFaces 2.x, then you should be using the following XML namespace instead:

```
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.prime.com.tr/ui"
```

That other question which you're linking to isn't talking about `<p:xxx>` tags, but about plain HTML tags like `<title>`, `<div>` and so on. It's just the coincidence that in case of that other question the `<input>` is been placed inside a `<p:panel>`.

Comment: okkkk BalusC... i have primefaces3.1 downloaded but it is not in /WEB-INF/lib folder. let me deploy my application again... anyway thank you for such a quick reply.

Comment: Why is that necessary for some JAR to be in lib directory while some can be added as User Library, when using Eclipse??

Comment: @Azfar: Only if you didn't properly configure the user library to automatically end up in `/WEB-INF/lib` of deployment. For future questions, please press `Ask Question` button in right top and don't abuse comments of a different question for that.

Answer (score -1):

Just dowmload the jar from [Java2s primefaces jar downloads](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/p/Downloadprimefaces35jar.htm)
and then add the jar to libraries folder in your project

Comment: Bad, bad, bad suggestion in multiple ways... First it refers to a prehistoric version of PrimeFaces, secondly, one should either use the PrimeFaces repository or maven-central... as a **_TRUSTED SOURCE_**

Comment: sorry, i am a beginner and i solve my problem like that. i just share my solution as a beginner.
thanks for your comment it will help me to answer technically next time