# JSF and Primefaces components doesn't render

Tags: eclipse, jsf, jakarta-ee, primefaces, glassfish

I am using primefaces4.0 with glassfish4 and java ee7 on Eclipse kepler.
I configure it (put the jar of the theme and primefaces on the lib and the java builpath and the class variables and add it on the `<htm>` and the web.xml) but the components doesn't appear at all. This is my code

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"   "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
 xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
    <h:head>
     <meta charset="windows-1256"></meta>
      <title>Connexion</title>
     </h:head>
     <h:body>
      <h:form>
      <fieldset> 
      <p:outputLabel for="email">Adresse email <span class="requis"></span>     </p:outputLabel>    
            <p:inputText id="email" value="" required="true" size="20" maxlength="60"  />
      <p:message id="emailMessage" for="email" errorClass="erreur" />
      <br/>  
       <p:outputLabel for="motdepasse">Mot de passe <span class="requis"></span></p:outputLabel>
      <p:inputSecret id="motdepasse" value="" required="true" size="20" maxlength="20"                       />
        <p:message id="motDePasseMessage" for="motdepasse"
            errorClass="erreur" />
        <br />
        <p:commandButton value="Connexion" action="" ajax="false" />
        </fieldset>
        </h:form>

                    </h:body>
                    </html>
```

and this is my web.xml file

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
        xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" 
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee       http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" 
id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1"
        >
        <display-name>Portail</display-name>
        <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
        </welcome-file-list>
         <context-param>
         <param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>
         <param-value>bootstrap</param-value>
          </context-param>
   <servlet>
     <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
       <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
        </servlet>
         <servlet-mapping>
         <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
         <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
         </servlet-mapping>

        </web-app>
```

Comment: Is standart JSF working?

Comment: how do i check that ?

Comment: Put a `<h:commandButton value="button" />` in your site and check if there is a button displaying.

Comment: No it's not working .

Comment: What is your jsf file called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out why the components wasn't rendring after reading this post [No TagLibrary associated to PrimeFaces's namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9674438/no-taglibrary-associated-to-primefacess-namespace).

I did put the jar in the lib but i didn't deploy them correctly that's why the tags weren't doing their work . I repeated the configuration this time with more attention and it finally worked.

Answer (score 2):

Your filename is `index.html` but in your web.xml you specified that you just wanted to render files that end with `.xhtml`. Rename your file to `index.xhtml`

Comment: the button now works but it's not using the theme style i specified in the web.xml

Comment: What does this stylesheet point to on your generated html page? `<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/project/faces/javax.faces.resource/theme.css?ln=primefaces-" />`

Comment: I don't have a refernece to a stylesheet .Actually in the primefaces guide they said that adding the jar of the theme is enough to meke it work (i am using the bootstrap theme)