# liferay : this page calls xml namespace http://java.sun.com//jstl/core declared with prefix c but no tag library exists for that namespace

Tags: jsf-2, liferay

I am using JSF project as a portlet in liferay.
Here my page includes template and a `viewScoped` managed bean and my page also uses `<ui:include>` and `<ui:composition>`.

I am not using core library but the warning is shown in the portal page when I add my portlet to liferay, this page calls xml namespace `http://java.sun.com//jstl/core` declared with prefix `c` but no tag library exists for that namespace.

Comment: Related (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2561956/this-page-calls-for-xml-namespace-declared-with-prefix-br-but-no-taglibrary-exis)[link]

Comment: its not too related since the title is about the prefix <br> and not c which deffers since c is core library and not like br an html tag

Comment: Please paste your code..

Comment: Do you really have `//` in taglib URI like that or is that just a careless typo? In any case .. read the JSTL tag documentation for the right URI.

Comment: the xml namespace i wrote is exactly the error
i turned through my classes and i didn't found this xml namespace which i mean i am not using this library in my xhtml files

Comment: my code is working in a dynamic web project but when i added the code to a portlet projecy the previuos error is shown

Comment: sorry @BalusC you meant // after com no offcourse its not like this its a careless typo
But any idea for that error